# What does int test[] = new int[0] mean?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

Will the above still create one element?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.

You'll get an IndexOutOfRangeException if you try to add anything to that array.

Comment: @Saif al Harthi: They call me quick-draw-mc-snorfus :)

Answer (score 9):

It's a simple empty array, just like an empty list or generically an empty collection.

The only difference is that you can't modify it later by adding elements.

It could be really useful for example when a method returns an array as result.
When the method has no results, instead of returning `null` you can return an empty array, so in the calling code you can skip a useless `null` check and go directly on the enumeration.

Comment: I don't think so, an array isn't dynamically sizable, so unlike an empty list, you can't add anything to it.

Comment: My simile wasn't intended to say that an empty array could be resized/modified, but rather that can be traversed like an empty list or collection...

Comment: I agree with your edit, however the OP asked (in a roundabout way) if any elements could be stored in the array. Clearly, that's not the case.

Comment: "Will the above still create one element?" english is not my first language, but it sounds to me like: "Does the above code still create an array with one element ?" but I can be wrong... Anyway, It doesn't matter he accepted your answer. :)