# Passing a C# array as a function parameter to allocate its memory does not work

Tags: c#, arrays

Since passing a C# array as a function parameter is pass-by-reference, that means I can modify the array in the function. So here I am trying to allocate and modify the array in the function:

```
void caller() {
   int array[];
   doStuff(array);

   if (array != null) {
      // never reaches here, even when I allocated the array of size 0
   }
}

void doStuff(int[] array) {
   int[] tmp = new int[0];
   array = new int[tmp.Length];
}
```

Problem is that the `array != null` check never turns out to be true, even when I have allocated an array of size 0. I've confirmed in documents that `new int[0]` is a valid allocation command. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: so what are you trying to reach?

Comment: It's *not* null, it's an empty array with length 0 that cannot be added to. Returning a zero-length array is just a way to get around a null check. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4477470

Comment: Did you try specifying length more than 0 ?  0 would not allocate any space i guess.

Comment: "Since passing a C# array as a function parameter is pass-by-reference" No. Reference types / value types is a different concept than pass-by-reference / pass-by-value. You are passing `array` by value. Pass it by reference with the `ref` keyword.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does int test\[\] = new int\[0\] mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477460/what-does-int-test-new-int0-mean)

Comment: Also, this does not compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will never work, unless you pass by reference.

Your first variable is null, when you pass it along you pass along a reference (by value!) to nothing. Your method than assigns its **copy** of the reference to some other array. That won't affect the original variable.

If you want that to work, you have to actually pass by reference (using `out` or `ref`).

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

since the array is initialized (with the new int command), it will never be null, just an declared empty space (with no data). You can check the length in the caller method, in the if.